# Real Analysis: $c^n \lt a$, there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ s.t. $(c+\epsilon)^n \lt a$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about a task I don't quite understand.
Let $c \gt 0$, $a \in \mathbb {R}$ and $n \in \mathbb {N}$.

If $c^n \lt a$, there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$,  s.t. $(c+\epsilon)^n \lt a$

If $c^n \gt a$, there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$,  s.t. $(c-\epsilon)^n \gt a$

I don't really understand where they're coming from. I guess it says that if $c^n \lt a$, there is always space for an $\epsilon \gt 0$ and the result will still be smaller than $a$. But that's where I'm stuck. Is there a simple way to put this?

Comment: Take $0 <\epsilon <a^{1/n}-c$ for the first one.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the info! How do i proceed from this though? Also, can I just do the reverse for the second one since they're so similar?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},$ $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ is increasing, if $c^n < a$ then $c< a^{1/n}$. Surely you can find some real number between $c$ and $a^{1/n}$, call it $b$; take $\varepsilon=b-c$. Do a similar trick for the other side.